# Is it a good practice to have trim in setter?

Tags: java

I'm doing a code review and I noticed such a code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SOME_TABLE")
public class SomeReportClass {

@Column(name = "REPORT_NUMBER", length = 6, nullable = false)
private String reportNumber;

.....
    public String getReportNumber() {
        return reportNumber;
    }

    public void setReportNumber(String reportNumber) {
        this.reportNumber = StringUtils.trimToNull(reportNumber);
    }
```

}

Every time I see trimming inside of a setter I feel that its not the clearest solution - what is the general practice with that issue?

Comment: Personally I don't see any issue here (even I have code like this), basic use of getters/setters to put valid and clean data (apart from encapsulation). So I think this shouldn't be a bad practice.

Comment: I do not see any problem with this code at all, as long as the dosumentation describes the behaviour correct this is way better than trimming strings all the time before setting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You know that You always need to trim the value this scenario will avoid code duplications, I.e. before your set You have to trim always and worry about where have You missed triming. In my opinion this is a good practice to have it in setter

Comment: What do You mean by saying "custom UserType that is automatically applied be better"?

Comment: The question is about "is it right or not". Defining custom UserType make no sense here because You have to reuse that in setter method again.

Answer (score 2):

Using setters to do anything else but transparently set the value violates the principle of the *separation of concerns*: with this design you have eternally intertwined the *setting* concern with the *trimming* concern. This is all great and peachy—as long as you are 100% sure that you will never, for the lifetime of your program, have as much as a single use case where you want the setting without the trimming. Once you do need it, the failure mode of this design is quite pathetic: you'll have a regular `set` method which is in fact "special" and be forced to add another `setWithoutTrimming` method, exactly the opposite of any sane assumption for a new programmer.

On a more general note, my choice is to use pure public fields (Hibernate supports them, as well as Spring, Jackson, etc.), which makes the semantics of setting them dead clear. If I have another concern, such as trimming, then I use an explicit call to a static method (a pure function) which does the necessary transformation. This leads to clear and obvious design, with no WATs such as "why is the getter returning a different value from what I just set?".

Comment: "why is the getter returning a different value from what I just set?" If the setter is well documented, you will know what value to expect.

Comment: If it were only that simple, this site's question count would be reduced by a factor of 10. As an extreme example, if I call a method `Qweprous`, and document well what it does, according to you I'm all fine.

Comment: I agree on the first part, but disagree on the second part. Having `private` fields allows you to change the internal structure without modifying the public API. Say, for example, what once was an `int` should now be a `String` to allow prefixes. Using overloaded setters will allow backwards compatibility, exposing internals won't (without hacks).

Comment: @IngoBürk Yes, there are some special circumstances which we can think up that would justify the accessors---it's just that, within my 15 years of professional experience with business software, I have yet to meet one such case. Note that we are discussing database entities here, not just some random Java objects. I would definitely *not* use public fields if I was designing a public API.

Comment: It's only an issue with public APIs anyway. I certainly agree on keeping the setter clean, otherwise you build a trap that isn't hard to find, but every single developer working with this code will run into it at least once, which is pretty annoying.

Comment: @IngoBürk As annoying as the 10,001st question on this site about "why is my string comparison yielding false?" :)

Comment: I agree, basic setters for the sake of maintainability and SoC. Better to validate trimmed values with RegExp for instance on the entity (Bean validation) instead of automatically and silently doing stuff on it. Also it is better to trim early, at the entity level, it seems too late.

Answer (score 0):

I feel as long as the method is documented clearly, the logic within it is fine.

At the end of the day, you don't want to end up with loads of places in the code where trimming is performed prior to calling the setter.

If you later decide that you no longer need to trim the string, you have only one change to make.

After all, the point of encapsulation is to put data and behaviour on that data in the same place.

Comment: And if he later decides that he has a *single special case* where he doesn't want the trimming? That's why it's a bad idea, in my book.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Add another setter for the special case?

Comment: And then you have the design turned upside-down: what should have been the basic case is now in a specialized setter, and the plain-vanilla setter is in fact special.

Answer (score 0):

This code is OK. The reason why setters are preferable to public values, is that you can introduce any logic inside them without breaking class`s interface. I have only one note, if you trim string in setter, then you should always trim it in getter. In you current case you have a problem:

1. get any blank value
2. set it back
3. and then try to get again

The first and the last get will be different. This is possible if table could be populated from outside entity.